# Derivation of a complex function with poles of order k

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have a function $f(s)= \frac{g(s)}{(s-a)^k}$ with poles of order k at a, where g is analytic different from zero, can we write

$f'(s)=\frac{g'(s)}{(s-a)^k}- \frac{k g(s)}{(s-a)^{k+1}}$ ? Does exist a Theorem about that?

Thanks

Comment: That is the product rule, applied to $g(s) \cdot (s-a)^{-k}$ ...

Comment: Thanks you, I see